# Master Page Server Error - Compiler Error Message: CS0426

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, iis-express, server-error

[image]

Hello! I've created a Master Page with ASP.Net, C# and right after that I created a "Web Form With Master Page" which I named Index.aspx so I could see the page in a browser. Now when I choose IIS Express (Google Chrome) or View in Browser, a Server Error is happening with error message "CS0426: The type name 'Site1' does not exist in the type 'MasterPage' ". Has it ever happened to you and do you know how I could fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
typeof(Site1)
```

instead of

```
typeof(MasterPage.Site1)
```

With MasterPage you are referring to [System.Web.UI.MasterPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.masterpage?view=netframework-4.8) but that is not the namespace of Site1

**Edit**: Based on your screenshot, I found the underlying problem. Your project is called MasterPage and the namespace as well. This results in a clash between System.Web.UI.MasterPage and your other classes. Please recreate the project with another project name and your problem will resolve itself.

Comment: I did that and now it says:  Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: 'Site1' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage'.

Source Error:


Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="Site1" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html>